# Any APIs or tools available to make web page tables highly configurable?

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jakarta-ee, wicket

I am in the process of designing a financial web page (using Java, Wicket, JQuery..) where one of the page has around 5 tables and each table has around 10-15 columns.

These columns should be highly configurable that means some clients want to view/hide selected columns or some clients may want to see column name as different from other client.

I want to make this page highly configurable through some XML files or some other way and I do not want to change java related code for this.

Are there any APIs or tools available for controlling or configuring web page tables and columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/)
- [Flexigrid](http://flexigrid.info/)

Both of these are jQuery plugins that are very nice to use (I have utilized both). I believe DataTables should be able to do everything you are looking for (and quite a bit more). Check out both sites and see what you think.

For more suggestions, check out this link: [15 Great jQuery Plugins for Better Table Manipulation](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-great-jquery-plugins-for-better-table-manipulation/)